# How Can I Convert Very Large Binary in String to Octal In Java

Tags: java

I have 1 String variable in my Java code and it contain of large binary digit. How can I convert it

```
String binary2 = JTextArea.gettext(); // this is a String variable
Long binary3 = Long.parseLong(binary2);
System.out.print(Long.toOctalString(binary3));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get use of `BigInteger` class which is more appropriate to use in your solution. It has an overloaded `toString()` method which takes *radix* (in your case radix = 8).

```
String largeBinary = "10101010100000100111011010101";
String octalVersion = (new BigInteger(largeBinary,2)).toString(8);
```

Answer (score 3):

Every three binary digits (`0` or `1`) represent exactly one octal digit (from `0` to `7`).

So I think the algorithm is simple: iterate over every 3 subsequent characters and convert them to one octal digit:

```
"000" -> "0"
"001" -> "1"
"010" -> "2"
"011" -> "3"
...
"111" -> "7"
```

Extra care need to be taken in the beginning if the length of the string is not a multiply of 3. Example:

```
"1001001110"

"10|101|001|110"
  2|  5|  1|  6
```

This approach does not require parsing the string and no extra memory. It can work on arbitrarily long input and is super fast

Comment: "It can work on arbitrarily long input" but only if you know the length in advance.

Comment: @Henry: you are right, +1. I am mentioning about the length but thanks for emphasizing that. On the other hand it can't be done *without* knowing the size in advance, and at least you don't have to parse the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

A `long` value can hold any number up to [2^63-1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE), which is sufficient for many applications. All you need to do is to provide the appropriate *radix* parameter to the [parseLong(String string, int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method (and the [toString(Long number, int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toString%28long,%20int%29) method).

```
long number = Long.parseLong(binaryString, 2);
String octalString = Long.toOctalString(number); // or Long.toString(number, 8);
```

Comment: I would hardly call 64 bits "very large"

Comment: Well, it depends on the context. The OP asked for a "large binary digit" without specifying environment or boundaries. My post defines the constraints to which it is applicable. Based on that, anyone looking for a solution can determine whether or not it will work based on their context.